# don't use jade layout

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I've defined a layout with jade. It's pretty simple. I just put it on the views folder and call it layout.jade

Is there any way to avoid one view to not use layout.jade as layout? This is how it's rendered:

```
exports.help = function(req, res) {
    res.render('help', { title: 'Help'} );
};
```

Thanks

Comment: Also consider looking at Express 3 - it doesn't use layouts by default.

Comment: That's the best solution I could find, but I have to migrate all, and I'm a little bit lazy at the moment... but that's the best solution =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to do a layout, do this:

```
exports.help = function(req, res) { 
    res.render('help', { layout: false, title: 'Help'} ); 
};
```

If you want to use another layout, you can do something like this (assuming your new layout file is called new_layout.jade):

```
exports.help = function(req, res) { 
    res.render('help', { layout: 'new_layout', title: 'Help'} ); 
};
```

[Here is a tutorial that I found helpful.](http://www.hacksparrow.com/express-js-tutorial.html)